# Reasoning in prolog issue

Tags: prolog, declarative-programming

```
foo([], Res).
foo([schedule(_, X)|Tail], Res) :- append(Res, X, Res2), 
                                   foo(Tail, Res2).
```

**Expected result:**

X is a list of values, Res is where the result should be stored.

Imagine that I call:

```
foo([schedule(c1,[t1,t2]),schedule(c2,[t3,t4])], X).
```

What the result should be is:

```
X = [t1,t2,t3,t4].
```

**But the result is:**

```
X = [] ;
X = [_G6951] ;
X = [_G6951,_G6957] ;
X = [_G6951,_G6957,_G6963] ;
X = [_G6951,_G6957,_G6963,_G6969] ;
X = [_G6951,_G6957,_G6963,_G6969,_G6975] ;
X = [_G6951,_G6957,_G6963,_G6969,_G6975,_G6981] ;
X = [_G6951,_G6957,_G6963,_G6969,_G6975,_G6981,_G6987] ;
```

and so on...

What is wrong in my code and reasoning, so that I understand what goes wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first clause, the result for an empty list of schedules should be an empty list of values:

```
foo([], []).
```

You put the arguments for `append/3` in wrong order (`Res` should be the concatenation of `X` and `Res2`):

```
foo([schedule(_, X)|Tail], Res) :-
    append(Res2, X, Res), 
    foo(Tail, Res2).
```

Now, in order to avoid Prolog do an infinite search for further solutions, change the order of the subgoals in the second clause:

```
foo([schedule(_, X)|Tail], Res) :-
    foo(Tail, Res2),
    append(Res2, X, Res).
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply! Why is the order of the subgoals wrong?